# Measure of sums of sets

Tags: measure-theory

Is it true that

$$m(A+B)\geq m(A)+m(B)$$? For any measurable sets $A,B$
where $A+B=\{x+y,x\in A,\,y\in B\}$
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general not; just consider e.g. the Dirac measure $\delta_1$ and the sets $$A := \{1\}, \qquad B := -A = \{-1\}.$$

Comment: The question was clearly about Lebesgue measure...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich "Clearly".....? The only tag is "measure theory" and $m$  is (imho) not a typical notation for the Lebesgue measure, but for an arbitrary measure.

Comment: First, in many books $m$ _is_ specifically Lebesgue measure; a general measure is $\mu$ instead. Second, and more to the point, the answer is so _obviously_ no for a general measure that the question "must" be about Lebesgue measure. If $\mu$ is a general measure then $\mu$ simply has nothing to do with the structure of $\Bbb R$ as an abelian group - there's simply no reason the result could possibly be true for a general measure.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I still don't agree with you. It is the task of the OP to ask the question in such a way that I don't have to guess what he might possibly mean. (In particular so if the OP doesn't care to add any thoughts on the problem.)

Comment: Well of course the OP should have clarified that he was referring to Lebesgue measure. The fact that the question was written less then optimally doesn't change the fact that it must be about Lebesgue measure, because it's simply senseless for a general measure.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich That's exactly what I mean by "guessing". Since the OP writes "$m(A+B)$" I also have to guess that the OP assumes that $A+B$ is measurable (because otherwise, as you are arguing, it doesn't make sense to talk about the meassure).....? From my point of view this is plain stupid.

Comment: m stands for Lebesgue measure, sorry that I did not mentioned that clearly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

@mathmath,

This is true for $A,B \in \mathbb{R}$ IF $A+B$ is also measurable. In general n-dimensional Euclidean space, the inequality looks a little different, i.e. if we define $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$, then indeed $m(A+B)^{1/n} \geq m(A)^{1/n} + m(B)^{1/n}$. The only sticking point here is that, even though both $A$ and $B$ may be measurable, $A+B$ is not necessarily measurable. If $A,B, A+B$ are each measurable, then the inequality in fact holds.

There are many proofs of this available online and in print, my favorite (and I believe clearest) of which from the Princeton Lecture Series proceed as follows: (1) show the inequality is true when $A,B$ are rectangles with side lengths $a,b$ respectively. (2) show inductively the inequality is true when $A,B$ are the union of finitely many rectangles. (3) extend to the case where $A,B$ are arbitrary compact sets (which implies that $A+B$ is also compact), then (4) approximating $A,B$ as measurable sets by using compact sets instead of rectangles...